# Removing 2 last characters from a string

Tags: bash, sed, ls

I'm trying to make a list of directories from two sources. The other directory has entries that can have -1 or -2 after them and I want to get rid of them.

ls output example:

```
something.something.anything-1
stuff.stuff.stuff.morestuff-2
st.uf.f
```

The code as how I have it now:

```
echo -e "\tDATA\t\t | \t\tSYSTEM"
for SYSTEM in `ls /system/app`; do
    for DATA in `ls /data/app | sed 's/-1*$//' | sed 's/-2*$//'`; do
        echo -n "$DATA | " 
    done
    echo "$SYSTEM"
done
```

It works just fine, but I'm currious if there's a better way of doing it, as I have to use sed twice. And I noticed there isn't really many good posts here to remove characters from strings using commands, this could be a good place to share your ideas.

**UPDATE:**

The updated code:

```
echo -e "\tDATA\t\t | \t\tSYSTEM"
for SYSTEM in `ls /system/app`; do
    for DATA in `ls /data/app | sed 's/-[[:digit:]]*$//'`; do
        echo -n "$DATA | " 
    done
    echo "$SYSTEM"
done
```

Wich works perfectly!

Comment: [Don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). `s/-[12]*$//`

Comment: Oh, well that's convenient :D Thanks!

Comment: If you want to remove only `-1` and `-2` but not `-12` or `-` use this `sed s/-[12]$//`

Comment: @karakfa Shouldn't you use `-\?` as they could also be positive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to remove the last two chars always:

```
echo "abcdefg" | sed 's/..$//g'
> abcde
```

Or you can use a tighter regex for all digits

```
echo "abcdefg-2" | sed 's/-[[:digit:]]$//g'
> abcdefg
```

Or just those two:

```
echo "abcdefg-2" | sed 's/-[12]$//g'
> abcdefg
```

Answer (score 1):

since you have stored your string in a variable, you can just use bash's built-in way to handle it:

```
kent$  x="1234567"    
kent$  echo ${x: :-2}
12345
```

Comment: Good answer. Or, a POSIX compliant way would be: `${x%??}`. Note that this slightly differs with your answer (that will fail if the lenght of `$x` is less than 2).

Comment: But that doesn't work on older bash versions and this script should be universal.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to remove the last 2 digits of any string use this:

```
$ echo -e "Hello-1\nHello-2" | sed 's/..$//'
Hello
Hello
```

Comment: That's otherwise nice, but the entries might not have -1 or -2 behind them. I see that's not explained in my question so I'll update it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

using a parameter expansion:

```
toto="abcd-1"
echo ${toto/%-[12]}
```